# Leaflet vs. MapLibre

Tags: library, maps, mapping

If you had to choose a mapping library for a web application, would you prefer Leaflet or MapLibre and what are the advantages/disadvantages? I am considering only those two, because they are both open source and have are quite easy-to-learn (that's why I am not considering Open Layers).

**Criteria that might be considered**

- Robustness, stability
- Current development
- Future development
- Documentation
- Community and help
- Technology (WebGL)

**Advantages of Leaflet:**

- Stable (available for years)
- good documentation, many plugins
- big community, easy to get help

**Advantages of MapLibre:**

- WebGL rendering (performance)
- Future development?

Comment: I'm not sure whether we do product comparisons nowadays. We didn't do that in the past.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So please [edit] your post, list your requirements and ask for software meeting those, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: In other words: Better outline what your requirements are, and be open for all recommendations meeting them. Who knows, there might be something fitting your needs even better. Without knowing them we cannot tell, so it's rather subjective and might even be the wrong result.

Comment: Maybe ask this (reworded) in the gis. SE community?

Comment: funny, on the GIS SE community I was told to post my question to Software Recommendations community..